# Convert multiple lines to single line and store in a variable for further analysis

Tags: python

In a mail, below lines are there. These lines are to be converted to
single line based on "List Num" . For printing, the below code is
working. But when I try to store in a variable as list or string, it is not working. Have given both the codes below.

```
mail = mailbody.splitlines()
nmail = ""
lnflg = "yes"
for line in mail:
    if re.findall(r'List Num:\s*([A-Z][0-9]{5}[A-Z]*)', line) != []:
        lnflg = "no"
        print "\n"
    if lnflg == "no":
        print line.rstrip(os.linesep),
    else:
        print line
```

Below code is not working, if I print using for loop

```
mail = mailbody.splitlines()
nmail = ""
lnflg = "yes"
for line in mail:
    if re.findall(r'List Num:\s*([A-Z][0-9]{5}[A-Z]*)', line) != []:
        lnflg = "no"
        #print "\n"
        nmail = nmail + "\n"
    if lnflg == "no":
        #print line.rstrip(os.linesep),
        nmail = nmail + line.rstrip(os.linesep)
    else:
        nmail = nmail + line
```

## For loop to print the nmail

```
for ln in nmail:
    print ln


 List Num:  L08586    Proj/Prob: 09P0087           Application: ACI 

 Load to:   TFDSA-SA      Until: ON PROGRAM BASE   Oncall Grp: TPFACI1

 Requester: HZDSF1 - ABCD       Work Phone: XX-XX-XXXXXXXX

 Approver:  FSDSJ8                                 Supervisor: ABCD XYZ

 Updated:   04/28/2011 (01:05:46 E)

 Segments:  PESSFH PESGSDG

 Purpose:   THIS IS RELATED TO 09P0087

            BARCODE WILL BE SUBMITTED IN ANOTHER PGMLST.


 List Num:  L08586    Proj/Prob: 09P0087           Application: ACI

 Load to:   TFDSA-SA      Until: ON PROGRAM BASE   Oncall Grp: TPFACI1

 Requester: HZDSF1 - ABCD       Work Phone: XX-XX-XXXXXXXX

 Approver:  FSDSJ8                                 Supervisor: ABCD XYZ

 Updated:   04/28/2011 (01:05:46 E)

 Segments:  PESSFH PESGSDG

 Purpose:   THIS IS RELATED TO 09P0087

            BARCODE WILL BE SUBMITTED IN ANOTHER PGMLST.
```

Expected output in a variable:

```
List Num:  L08586    Proj/Prob: 09P0087           Application: ACI Load to:   TFDSA-SA      Until: ON PROGRAM BASE   Oncall Grp: TPFACI1 Requester: HZDSF1 - ABCD    Work Phone: XX-XX-XXXXXXXX Approver:  FSDSJ8                                 Supervisor: ABCD XYZ Updated:   04/28/2011 (01:05:46 E) Segments:  PESSFH PESGSDG Purpose:   THIS IS RELATED TO 09P0087             BARCODE WILL BE SUBMITTED IN ANOTHER PGMLST.

 List Num:  L08586    Proj/Prob: 09P0087           Application: ACI Load to:   TFDSA-SA      Until: ON PROGRAM BASE   Oncall Grp: TPFACI1 Requester: HZDSF1 - ABCD    Work Phone: XX-XX-XXXXXXXX Approver:  FSDSJ8                                 Supervisor: ABCD XYZ Updated:   04/28/2011 (01:05:46 E) Segments:  PESSFH PESGSDG Purpose:   THIS IS RELATED TO 09P0087             BARCODE WILL BE SUBMITTED IN ANOTHER PGMLST.
```

Comment: show you actual data exactly as it is,  what is `BARCODE WILL BE SUBMITTED IN ANOTHER PGMLST.` suppoesed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `BARCODE` line to delimit the lines with groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby
with open("foo.txt") as f:
    grouped, data = groupby(map(str.rstrip,f), key=lambda x: x.strip().startswith("BARCODE")), []
    for k,v in grouped:
        if not k:
            data.append("".join(v)+"".join(next(grouped)[1]))


print(data[0])
print()
print(data[1])
```

Input:

```
List Num:  L08586    Proj/Prob: 09P0087           Application: ACI
Load to:   TFDSA-SA      Until: ON PROGRAM BASE   Oncall Grp: TPFACI1
Requester: HZDSF1 - ABCD       Work Phone: XX-XX-XXXXXXXX
Approver:  FSDSJ8                                 Supervisor: ABCD XYZ
Updated:   04/28/2011 (01:05:46 E)
Segments:  PESSFH PESGSDG
Purpose:   THIS IS RELATED TO 09P0087
BARCODE WILL BE SUBMITTED IN ANOTHER PGMLST.
List Num:  L08586    Proj/Prob: 09P0087           Application: ACI
Load to:   TFDSA-SA      Until: ON PROGRAM BASE   Oncall Grp: TPFACI1
Requester: HZDSF1 - ABCD       Work Phone: XX-XX-XXXXXXXX
Approver:  FSDSJ8                                 Supervisor: ABCD XYZ
Updated:   04/28/2011 (01:05:46 E)
Segments:  PESSFH PESGSDG
Purpose:   THIS IS RELATED TO 09P0087
BARCODE WILL BE SUBMITTED IN ANOTHER PGMLST.
```

Output:

```
List Num:  L08586    Proj/Prob: 09P0087           Application: ACILoad to:   TFDSA-SA      Until: ON PROGRAM BASE   Oncall Grp: TPFACI1Requester: HZDSF1 - ABCD       Work Phone: XX-XX-XXXXXXXXApprover:  FSDSJ8                                 Supervisor: ABCD XYZUpdated:   04/28/2011 (01:05:46 E)Segments:  PESSFH PESGSDGPurpose:   THIS IS RELATED TO 09P0087BARCODE WILL BE SUBMITTED IN ANOTHER PGMLST.


List Num:  L08586    Proj/Prob: 09P0087           Application: ACILoad to:   TFDSA-SA      Until: ON PROGRAM BASE   Oncall Grp: TPFACI1Requester: HZDSF1 - ABCD       Work Phone: XX-XX-XXXXXXXXApprover:  FSDSJ8                                 Supervisor: ABCD XYZUpdated:   04/28/2011 (01:05:46 E)Segments:  PESSFH PESGSDGPurpose:   THIS IS RELATED TO 09P0087BARCODE WILL BE SUBMITTED IN ANOTHER PGMLST.
```